# What causes many locked .etl files to accumulate?

Tags: windows, windows-10

`C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Temp` keeps filling with folders in the format

```
Report.{some guid}.number
```

Opening the folder reveals a file

```
{some guid}.number.m.etl
```

These files accumulate as I work on my PC (mostly Visual Studio development) until I run out of space on my C: drive. Most of the files are locked, so I can't remove them until rebooting. I lose 15GB disk space in a few hours of work.

This is a fairly recent thing (last month or two, maybe) and there haven't been noteworthy changes to my installed software in that time.

What's creating these files at this crazy rate and how can I stop it from happening?

Here's a report.txt from tracerpt for one of the small ones

```
Files Processed:
    18A9D359-FA3E-4411-A1F5-5BEC2ED7ED51.91.m.etl
Total Buffers Processed 509
Total Events  Processed 106391
Total Events  Lost      0
Start Time              Thursday, November 9, 2017
End Time                Thursday, November 9, 2017
Elapsed Time            2 sec
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|Event Count   Event Name           Task            Opcode          Version         Guid                                  |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|          3   EventTrace           0               RDComplete      2               {68fdd900-4a3e-11d1-84f4-0000f80464e3}|
|          3   EventTrace           0               Extension       2               {68fdd900-4a3e-11d1-84f4-0000f80464e3}|
|          3   EventTrace           0               EndExtension    2               {68fdd900-4a3e-11d1-84f4-0000f80464e3}|
|          1   EventTrace           0               Header          2               {68fdd900-4a3e-11d1-84f4-0000f80464e3}|
|          1                        0               37              0               {9b79ee91-b5fd-41c0-a243-4248e266e9d0}|
|          1                        0               32              0               {9b79ee91-b5fd-41c0-a243-4248e266e9d0}|
|         14                        0               35              0               {9b79ee91-b5fd-41c0-a243-4248e266e9d0}|
|          2                        0               34              0               {9b79ee91-b5fd-41c0-a243-4248e266e9d0}|
|          1                        0               33              0               {9b79ee91-b5fd-41c0-a243-4248e266e9d0}|
|        336   Process              0               DCStart         4               {3d6fa8d0-fe05-11d0-9dda-00c04fd7ba7c}|
|          1   Thread               0               End             3               {3d6fa8d1-fe05-11d0-9dda-00c04fd7ba7c}|
|         58   Thread               0               Start           3               {3d6fa8d1-fe05-11d0-9dda-00c04fd7ba7c}|
|       4331   Thread               0               DCStart         3               {3d6fa8d1-fe05-11d0-9dda-00c04fd7ba7c}|
|          1                        0               33              2               {b3e675d7-2554-4f18-830b-2762732560de}|
|         44                        0               37              2               {b3e675d7-2554-4f18-830b-2762732560de}|
|        323                        0               36              2               {b3e675d7-2554-4f18-830b-2762732560de}|
|        345                        0               0               2               {b3e675d7-2554-4f18-830b-2762732560de}|
|        342                        0               64              0               {b3e675d7-2554-4f18-830b-2762732560de}|
|          1   Image                0               KernelBase      2               {2cb15d1d-5fc1-11d2-abe1-00a0c911f518}|
|        351   Image                0               DCStart         3               {2cb15d1d-5fc1-11d2-abe1-00a0c911f518}|
|       6576   PerfInfo             0               SampleProf      2               {ce1dbfb4-137e-4da6-87b0-3f59aa102cbc}|
|          7                        0               33              0               {bbccf6c1-6cd1-48c4-80ff-839482e37671}|
|          9                        0               32              0               {bbccf6c1-6cd1-48c4-80ff-839482e37671}|
|          3   Microsoft-Windows-DotNETRuntimeRundown 1               DCStartComplete  1               {a669021c-c450-4609-a035-5af59af4df18}|
|      45189   Microsoft-Windows-DotNETRuntimeRundown 1               MethodDCStartILToNativeMap  0               {a669021c-c450-4609-a035-5af59af4df18}|
|      46641   Microsoft-Windows-DotNETRuntimeRundown 1               DCStartVerbose  1               {a669021c-c450-4609-a035-5af59af4df18}|
|        135   Microsoft-Windows-DotNETRuntimeRundown 2               ModuleDCStart   2               {a669021c-c450-4609-a035-5af59af4df18}|
|        132   Microsoft-Windows-DotNETRuntimeRundown 2               DomainModuleDCStart  1               {a669021c-c450-4609-a035-5af59af4df18}|
|        132   Microsoft-Windows-DotNETRuntimeRundown 2               AssemblyDCStart  1               {a669021c-c450-4609-a035-5af59af4df18}|
|          6   Microsoft-Windows-DotNETRuntimeRundown 2               AppDomainDCStart  1               {a669021c-c450-4609-a035-5af59af4df18}|
|          3   Microsoft-Windows-DotNETRuntimeRundown 1               DCStartInit     1               {a669021c-c450-4609-a035-5af59af4df18}|
|          3   Microsoft-Windows-DotNETRuntimeRundown 19              Start           0               {a669021c-c450-4609-a035-5af59af4df18}|
|        831   StackWalk            0               Stack           2               {def2fe46-7bd6-4b80-bd94-f57fe20d0ce3}|
|          1                        0               0               0               {9e5f9046-43c6-4f62-ba13-7b19896253ff}|
|         16                        0               0               1               {9e5f9046-43c6-4f62-ba13-7b19896253ff}|
|          1   SystemConfig         0               TelemetryConfiguration 2               {01853a65-418f-4f36-aefc-dc0f1d2fd235}|
|          1   SystemConfig         0               CodeIntegrity   2               {01853a65-418f-4f36-aefc-dc0f1d2fd235}|
|          1   SystemConfig         0               FlightIds       2               {01853a65-418f-4f36-aefc-dc0f1d2fd235}|
|          1   SystemConfig         0               DeviceFamily    2               {01853a65-418f-4f36-aefc-dc0f1d2fd235}|
|          1   SystemConfig         0               Platform        2               {01853a65-418f-4f36-aefc-dc0f1d2fd235}|
|          1   SystemConfig         0               Power           2               {01853a65-418f-4f36-aefc-dc0f1d2fd235}|
|          1   SystemConfig         0               CPU             3               {01853a65-418f-4f36-aefc-dc0f1d2fd235}|
|        314   SystemConfig         0               Services        3               {01853a65-418f-4f36-aefc-dc0f1d2fd235}|
|         18   SystemConfig         0               IRQ             3               {01853a65-418f-4f36-aefc-dc0f1d2fd235}|
|        174   SystemConfig         0               PnP             5               {01853a65-418f-4f36-aefc-dc0f1d2fd235}|
|          1   SystemConfig         0               OpticalDisk     2               {01853a65-418f-4f36-aefc-dc0f1d2fd235}|
|          5   SystemConfig         0               Defragmentation 2               {01853a65-418f-4f36-aefc-dc0f1d2fd235}|
|          3   SystemConfig         0               LogDisk         2               {01853a65-418f-4f36-aefc-dc0f1d2fd235}|
|          7   SystemConfig         0               PhyDisk         2               {01853a65-418f-4f36-aefc-dc0f1d2fd235}|
|          5   SystemConfig         0               NIC             2               {01853a65-418f-4f36-aefc-dc0f1d2fd235}|
|          1   SystemConfig         0               DPI             2               {01853a65-418f-4f36-aefc-dc0f1d2fd235}|
|          7   SystemConfig         0               Video           2               {01853a65-418f-4f36-aefc-dc0f1d2fd235}|
|          1                        0               37              0               {ed54dff8-c409-4cf6-bf83-05e1e61a09c4}|
|          1                        0               35              0               {ed54dff8-c409-4cf6-bf83-05e1e61a09c4}|
|          1                        0               33              0               {ed54dff8-c409-4cf6-bf83-05e1e61a09c4}|
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|Event Count   Event Name           Event ID        Version         Guid                                  |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|         10   EventTrace           0               2               {68fdd900-4a3e-11d1-84f4-0000f80464e3}|
|         19                        0               0               {9b79ee91-b5fd-41c0-a243-4248e266e9d0}|
|        336   Process              0               4               {3d6fa8d0-fe05-11d0-9dda-00c04fd7ba7c}|
|       4390   Thread               0               3               {3d6fa8d1-fe05-11d0-9dda-00c04fd7ba7c}|
|        342                        0               0               {b3e675d7-2554-4f18-830b-2762732560de}|
|        713                        0               2               {b3e675d7-2554-4f18-830b-2762732560de}|
|          1   Image                0               2               {2cb15d1d-5fc1-11d2-abe1-00a0c911f518}|
|        351   Image                0               3               {2cb15d1d-5fc1-11d2-abe1-00a0c911f518}|
|       6576   PerfInfo             0               2               {ce1dbfb4-137e-4da6-87b0-3f59aa102cbc}|
|         16                        0               0               {bbccf6c1-6cd1-48c4-80ff-839482e37671}|
|      46641   Microsoft-Windows-DotNETRuntimeRundown 143             1               {a669021c-c450-4609-a035-5af59af4df18}|
|          3   Microsoft-Windows-DotNETRuntimeRundown 145             1               {a669021c-c450-4609-a035-5af59af4df18}|
|          3   Microsoft-Windows-DotNETRuntimeRundown 147             1               {a669021c-c450-4609-a035-5af59af4df18}|
|      45189   Microsoft-Windows-DotNETRuntimeRundown 149             0               {a669021c-c450-4609-a035-5af59af4df18}|
|        132   Microsoft-Windows-DotNETRuntimeRundown 151             1               {a669021c-c450-4609-a035-5af59af4df18}|
|        135   Microsoft-Windows-DotNETRuntimeRundown 153             2               {a669021c-c450-4609-a035-5af59af4df18}|
|        132   Microsoft-Windows-DotNETRuntimeRundown 155             1               {a669021c-c450-4609-a035-5af59af4df18}|
|          6   Microsoft-Windows-DotNETRuntimeRundown 157             1               {a669021c-c450-4609-a035-5af59af4df18}|
|          3   Microsoft-Windows-DotNETRuntimeRundown 187             0               {a669021c-c450-4609-a035-5af59af4df18}|
|        831   StackWalk            0               2               {def2fe46-7bd6-4b80-bd94-f57fe20d0ce3}|
|          1                        5               0               {9e5f9046-43c6-4f62-ba13-7b19896253ff}|
|          6                        7               1               {9e5f9046-43c6-4f62-ba13-7b19896253ff}|
|          6                        8               1               {9e5f9046-43c6-4f62-ba13-7b19896253ff}|
|          2                        9               1               {9e5f9046-43c6-4f62-ba13-7b19896253ff}|
|          2                        10              1               {9e5f9046-43c6-4f62-ba13-7b19896253ff}|
|         35   SystemConfig         0               2               {01853a65-418f-4f36-aefc-dc0f1d2fd235}|
|        333   SystemConfig         0               3               {01853a65-418f-4f36-aefc-dc0f1d2fd235}|
|        174   SystemConfig         0               5               {01853a65-418f-4f36-aefc-dc0f1d2fd235}|
|          3                        0               0               {ed54dff8-c409-4cf6-bf83-05e1e61a09c4}|
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: They are event trace logs. They are usually managed in event viewer. But they can be enabled by various means as a debugging tool. See if you can [open](https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-read-an-etl-file) the log file and see what is creating it.

Comment: @Appleoddity Thanks. I added output for one of them to the question. I can't see from that information what's creating them,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The clue to what is causing this is:

```
|      45189   Microsoft-Windows-DotNETRuntimeRundown 1               MethodDCStartILToNativeMap  0               {a669021c-c450-4609-a035-5af59af4df18}|
|      46641   Microsoft-Windows-DotNETRuntimeRundown 1               DCStartVerbose  1               {a669021c-c450-4609-a035-5af59af4df18}|
```

Here we find over 45,000 occurrences of each event.

I'm not familiar with this particular type of logging, but this appears to be events from the Common Language Runtime provider as part of the .Net framework. So you are right that it is likely happening while you are using Visual Studio. I  believe this might be part of "Application Domain Resource Monitoring." We can see the provider and GUID. In this case, we can see specifically "Microsoft-Windows-DotNETRuntimeRundown" using a GUID `{a669021c-c450-4609-a035-5af59af4df18}`.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/app-domain-resource-monitoring

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/performance/clr-etw-providers

It appears you have enabled logging at level 5, either within your code or elsewhere, and that is generating a large number of events.

We'll need to reduce the logging level for this provider. Default is 0.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/performance/controlling-logging

From an administrative command prompt, it looks like we can use:

`logman stop clrevents -ets`

This should stop the logging, but I'm not sure if this is persistent or the only place to do this. You'll have to review some of the links I provided to figure out where this got enabled and how to lower the verbosity level.

The command `logman query providers "{a669021c-c450-4609-a035-5af59af4df18}"` will list the keywords that the provider can log on. The tracing level for each keyword can be adjusted.

Comment: When I try the `logman` command as admin, I get the error `Data Collector Set was not found.` I'll continue to investigate based on the other information you found.